# Download MySQL and "Connection Warning (Local instance 3306)" popped up

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench, ventura

I cannot access mysql editor through workbench and it is quite frustrating. The installation worked smoothly and it shows to be active on my settings; however, [this keeps popping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO7JN.png). I don't know if I downloaded the wrong version or did something wrong. [This is my Mac version. here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwb1v.png). I hate mac so much.

I reverse engineered it; however, I cannot seem to access the mysqleditor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the prompt in the first image, your MySQL Server version is older than 5.6, and you should use MySQL Workbench version 6.3. On [this site](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/), you can choose the version and download it.